# WSDL2Apex for Visual Studio Code & Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, wsdl, wsdl2apex, visualstudiocode

Is there a WSDL2Apex extension for Visual Studio Code, which would allow us to use a WSDL Url or file to generate Apex classes in our Visual Studio Code Salesforce DX project?

Comment: It went to opensource afaik, so you can make your own -- https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex

Comment: @kurunve thanks. I was aware of `WSDL2Apex`. But I was hoping for a solution which is more integrated with Visual Studio Code

Comment: Do you want to regenerate the classes from the CLI, (which in turn could be automated from VSC)? It wouldn't be to difficult to rework my version of WSDL2Apex to support this.

Comment: @DanielBallinger yeah that would be great. If it could be called from the SFFX CLI and VS Code command palette :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the existing SFDX plugin from Wade Wegner - [wadewegner/sfdx-wsdl2apex-plugin](https://github.com/wadewegner/sfdx-wsdl2apex-plugin). That will give you CLI level access to the Java implmentation for WSDL2Apex.

You could combine that with a custom [Visual Studio Code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world) to expose it in the command palette.